# jQuery 1.5.1 script for working tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you please help me do the scripting of the tabs using the 1.5.1 version of jQuery?

i got my html, css code setup already. Earlier i tried doing it using 1.5.1 but didn't get it right. But using the jQuery 1.8.3 works fine i don't know why my script doesn't work with 1.5.1.

I need to use 1.5.1 for such reasons. your solution will be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/uc3gzxye/' here's what i have as of now.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use 1.5.1?

Comment: because our instructor said we need to use 1.5.1, we cant use any other version. Please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` function used to be called `live()`

I have updated your fiddle, it works in 1.6 and should hopefully work in 1.5 as well

```
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').live('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I think I'm having issues with my computer, should be at http://jsfiddle.net/uc3gzxye/2/ and I have pasted the code here as well

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you want. 
Do you want to show tab1 div when click the first tab, and show tab2 div when click the second tab? 
If it is what you want, the please refer to the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tab1").hide();
     $("#tab2").hide();

    $('a[href="#tab1"]').click(function(){

       $("#tab1").show().delay(5000);
       $("#tab2").hide();

    });

        $('a[href="#tab2"]').click(function(){

       $("#tab2").show().delay(5000);
       $("#tab1").hide();

    });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/uc3gzxye/3/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advise, yes you are right with the solution. thank you!

Comment: Ok, no worries. By the way, you should mark my answer as a correct answer for future viewers, otherwise they may get confused.